# screen -S <name> gives "Cannot exec 'usr/bin/bash'" in ssh session

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen

When I try to open a new screen session on a VPS via ssh using `screen -S name` I get an error saying `Cannot exec 'usr/bin/bash': No such file or directory`. This is a problem that started occurring today on all my VPSs irrespective of service provider. Before today, I had no issue creating new screen sessions with the method above.

Already tried reinstalling screen and rebooting the servers but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by copying `/bin/bash` to `usr/bin/bash`. Not entirely sure why the issue arose in the first place though.

Comment: Only thing worked for me was this. I believe it's about $PATH variable but not had a chance to work with it so ended up copying bin/bash to usr/bin/bash.